# Mapping Relationships with EF Core Fluent API with two entities of the same type

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have been trying to use the fluent api to configure appropriate mapping for the image below. (If someone marks this as a duplicate, for the love of all that is holy, please include the relevant link!  I've spent days combing stackoverflow.)

[image: Table Map]

A main thought I am aiming for is that all entities will have an **EnterpriseID** that would be used as a sharding key.

The Enterprise table contains two Contacts, a PrimaryContact and a BillingContact.

What I would like to do is create a new Enterprise with a code generated **GUID** ID as well as two contacts (Primary and Billing), assign the **Enterprise** **ID** to those and call SaveChanges on the **TrackingState**.Added object hierarchy (which at this point is Enterprise->Contacts->Addresses.

Without any Fluent mapping, **EF Core** 2.1 says.. "Both relationships between 'Contact' and 'Enterprise.BillingContact' and between 'Contact' and 'Enterprise.PrimaryContact' could use {'**EnterpriseID**'} as the foreign key. To resolve this configure the foreign key properties explicitly on at least one of the relationships."

I have attempted many configuratons and either wind up with a DB that only has one of the Contact properties in the Enterprise table defined, or the whole mess devolves into FK / cyclical hell.

Here are current class stubs..

```cs
public class Enterprise
{
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public Contact PrimaryContact {get; set;}
  public Contact BillingContact {get; set;}
}

public class Contact
{
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public Guid EnterpriseID {get; set;}
  public string FName {get; set;}
  public string LName {get; set;}
  public Address Address {get; set;}
}

public class Store
{
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public Guid EnterpriseID {get; set;}
  public Contact PrimaryContact {get; set;}
}

public class Order
{
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public Guid EnterpriseID {get; set;}
  public Guid StoreID {get; set;}
  public Contact CustomerContact {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public Guid EnterpriseID {get; set;}
  public string Lines {get; set;}
}
```

I would really appreciate some advice on how to configure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Enterprise table contains two Contacts, a PrimaryContact and a BillingContact.

Then the relationship among `Enterprise`, `Contact` and `Address` should be as follows:

```
public class Enterprise
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public Guid PrimaryContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact PrimaryContact { get; set; }

    public Guid BillingContactId { get; set; }
    public Contact BillingContact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public Address Address {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
   [Key]
   public Guid ContactId {get; set;}
   public string Lines {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the *Fluent API* configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>().HasOne(e => e.PrimaryContact)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Enterprise>(e => e.PrimaryContactId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Enterprise>().HasOne(e => e.BillingContact)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Enterprise>(e => e.BillingContactId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().HasOne(c => c.Address)
            .WithOne().HasForeignKey<Address>(a => a.ContactId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think I grok where I was going wrong now...  I was trying to place the FK on the Contact instead of Enterprise.  Thanks for your help.